# Combobox not showing DisplayMember value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, datasource

I am trying to use a combobox to display a list(of T) of custom objects.  The object looks like this:

```
    Public Class KeyValue(Of K, V)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal key As K,
                   ByVal value As V)
        Me.Key = key
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Property Key As K
    Public Property Value As V

End Class
```

I populate the combobox like this:

```
        Private Sub FillCountries()
        If cboCountry.DataSource Is Nothing Then
            Dim table As DataTable = GetTableByName(GetQualifiedName(Of DataModel.TableModels.Reference.CountryMain), True)
            Dim source As New List(Of KeyValue(Of String, String))
            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                source.Add(New KeyValue(Of String, String)(row.Item("pkCountryCode").ToString,
                                                           row.Item(CountryName).ToString))
            Next
            cboCountry.DisplayMember = "Value"
            cboCountry.ValueMember = "Key"
            cboCountry.DataSource = source
        End If
    End Sub
```

I've tried setting DisplayMember first as well as ValueMember first.  Either way, I get a combobox that displays the KeyValue.ToString() value instead of the value of the Value property.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the table as a Datasource to the combobox?

Comment: Also, why would you want to display the Value instead of the Key which is a bit more standard?

Comment: Code works, so I don't see your issue.  CountryName should be in "quotes".

Comment: I was originally using the table and switched to the object just to make sure that the table wasn't the issue.  As for the key and value, I was just trying things out to see if it would work.  I've never had this issue before with a combobox.

Comment: As Lars says, this code works. My guess is that you do not fetch any data in the function GetTableByName.